# BS Flight from Madrid to New York with a stopover in London. (Aug 9th)

Tags: visas, uk, transit, us-residents, cuban-citizens

Wife is a Cuban Citizen with USA Permanent Residence Card and we just found out that she might need a Transit Visa. Our travel date is July 25th, not enough time to file for this visa.

can anyone advise if this transit visa is a must or is there an alternative solution?  We'll be approx. two hours in London and and most likely won't leave the secure area while moving from one plane to the next.

Comment: British Airways Flight from Madrid....

Comment: This is our #1 most frequently asked question; the linked Q&A contains the answer.